# how to parse this data structure in corona sdk?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

hello I have this json data

> "bookinfo": { "result1":{"page":"1","text":"aa","audio":"1.mp3"},
>   "result2":{"page":"1","text":"bb","audio":"2.mp3"},
>   "result3":{"page":"1","text":"cc.","audio":"3.mp3"} }

and I use this code

```
  local function networkListener( event )
      if ( event.isError ) then
          print ( "ERROR!" )
      else
          local jsonContent = json.decode(event.response).bookinfo
          print(jsonContent[1].text )
      end
    end
```

json data don't have only have 3 result1,2,3 ... but hundreds, this where the difficulty come from.

My question is `jsonContent[1].text` don't work, how to access sub-elements without knowing their names ? just by indexing?

** note : I'm sure this is not a duplicate of any question in stackoverflow, thanks a lot.

Comment: "how to access sub-elements without knowing their names ? just by indexing?" - how do you plan on indexing if you don't know the names?

Comment: You can use `for k,v in pairs(jsonContent) do print(v.text) end`

Comment: Why is your json data using names like "result1", "result2", ... instead of using an array?

Comment: This is going on memory to a project of mine, but when I had json data in a table, it was a 2D table and its first index was found at table[2][1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a dirty workaround that at least works in my case, printing the dictionary elements get's un-ordered... so I followed this approach.

I added this function to main

```
function tablelength(T)
  local count = 0
  for _ in pairs(T) do count = count + 1 end
  return count
end
```

then I used this

```
   local count = 0

    local function networkListener( event )
        if (event.isError) then
            print ( "ERROR!" )
        else
            local jsonContent = json.decode(event.response)
            count = tablelength(jsonContent.bookinfo); print(count)
            local content = jsonContent
            local texts = {}
            for i=1,count do texts[i] = jsonContent.bookinfo["result"..i].text end
        end
    end
```

if you have a better solution please let us know.